# かっこ内の文字の抜き出しで、結果が空の場合は空文字を返したい

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

引数 `str` で渡された文字列から `()` で括られた範囲を見つけ、その部分の文字列を返します。

- `()` の中身が空の場合は空文字を返します。
- `()` が複数ある場合には最初に見つかった括弧の中身を返します。(最短一致となる)
- `()` が見つからない場合はnullを返します。

`()` の中身が空の場合は空文字を返したいのですが、nullと表示されてしまいます。
ご教示いただけますでしょうか？

```
function extractStr(str) {
  var ret = /\((.+?)\)/.exec(str);
  return ret ? ret[1] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ()の中身が空の場合は空文字を返したいのですが、nullと表示されてしまいます。

正規表現は `\((.+?)\)` となっていて、括弧内は `(.+?)` と指定されています。 `+?` は1文字以上ですので、 **()の中身が空の場合**は該当せずマッチに失敗します。空でも成功してほしいなら正規表現は0文字以上を表す`*?`を使って `\((.*?)\)` とする必要があります。

Comment: ご丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございました！

Comment: @mkmk [ありがとうコメントは不要](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)です。解決したのであれば[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をお願いします。